# Swift nested enum common type

Tags: swift, enums

Is there a *cleaner* or a *shorter* way to write the following?

```
protocol AProtocol {}

enum AnEnum {
 enum NestedEnum1: AProtocol {
    case A1, B1
  }

  enum NestedEnum2: AProtocol {
    case A2, B2
  }
}

func makeItRain(_ rain: AProtocol)
```

The dream would be to just write the following –

```
func makeItRain(_ rain: AnEnum)
```

– that would accept *NestedEnum1* and *NestedEnum2* as input (without them having to conform to the *AProtocol*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enum AnEnum {
    enum NestedEnum1 {
        case A1, B1
    }

    enum NestedEnum2 {
        case A2, B2
    }

    case nestedEnum1(NestedEnum1)
    case nestedEnum2(NestedEnum2)
}
```

and in your `makeItRain` func you switch with `.nestedEnum1` and `nestedEnum2` cases.

// Well you have to wrap `AnEnum.NestedEnum1` and `AnEnum.NestedEnum2` in those cases of `AnEnum` tho.